# Pullback of a nef divisor under a finite morphism.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $X \rightarrow Y$ is a finite morphism of surfaces and $D$ is a nef divisor on $Y$, is the pullback of $D$ nef on X? I am interested in finite covers of Hirzebruch surfaces and need to know if some divisors coming from below are nef.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and you don't even need to know that $f$ is finite. If $C$ is an integral curve on $X$, we have the projection formula $f^*D \cdot C = D \cdot f_*C$; and $f_*C$ is a non-negative multiple of an integral curve on $Y$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is worth adding here that if you do assume that f is finite, then the pullback of an ample divisor remains ample.